# c# why when the path is "C:" the directoryInfo takes me to the application folder?

Tags: c#, path, directoryinfo

Why when i give the path "c:" it changed me directly to application folder?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("c:");
        Console.WriteLine(dir.FullName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The output is the following:

> c:\users...\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\consoleApplication9\bin\debug

But when I give `@"c:\"` it goes to disk `c:`
despite that `"d:"` and `@"d:\"` takes to disk `d:`.

So I need a way to let `"c:"` takes to disk `c:`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because that's how it's worked since 1983 and it would be confusing to change it now!

Comment: Try `DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");` or `DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");`.

Comment: doesn't work for my application my application i just edit my question  .. check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        string YourDir = "c:";

        if (!YourDir.Substring(YourDir.Length - 1, 1).Equals(@"\"))
            YourDir += @"\";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(YourDir); 
        Console.WriteLine(dir.FullName); 
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
```

Comment: you are the only who got my point .. so i guess that this's the only way to do right
thanks alot

Comment: you are the only who got my point .. so i guess that this's the only way to do right
thanks alot

Comment: @MurHafSoz: If lots of people are failing to understand you, you should consider explaining yourself more clearly.

Comment: i didn't asked for an explanation because i've already know my problem .. i asked for a solution .. and he's the only one who understood

Comment: @MurHafSoz: I assure you that you did ask for an explanation. Your question begins with "why does", which is a request for an explanation. If you wanted to know how to do something then your question should have begun with "how do I".

Comment: What's up with the substring and the equals? Why not just EndsWith?

Answer (score 15):

Just `"c:"` means "the current directory on the C drive" whereas `@"c:\"` means "root of the C drive". This works the same way from a command prompt...

Answer (score 6):

C: is just the volume specifier, so it will change to your current path on that volume, which would be the working path of the application.

D: takes you to root simply because your current folder for that volume happens to be at root.

Comment: that means you should be using `C:\` which specifies the path on the disk as well

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use the following

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {          
      DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
      Console.WriteLine(dir.FullName);
      Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

The Base Directory at the time when you do c: the application doesn't understand that so it returns the Directory of where the application was launched / run from.

Notice that dir = {.} if you would have passed in a literal directory path you would have gotten the expected results..