# Creating DirectoryInfo object for drive root

Tags: c#, .net, directory

In a C# program I am creating an instance of DirectoryInfo. Normally it does not seem to require a trailing slash after a directory name. But if I pass in "C:", rather than getting the root directory for my hard drive I get the directory where my executable is! This certainly seems like a bug but is there some hidden behavior that I am missing?

Comment: Check out @JonSkeet's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9130398/2457029)

Comment: Very good explanation from GazTheDestroyer on another question which turned out to be identical: 

C: is just the volume specifier, so it will change to your current path on that volume, which would be the working path of the application.

D: takes you to root simply because your current folder for that volume happens to be at root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't explicitly called out in the documentation, but using just (drive): isn't listed as a valid path specification among those that are listed.

The behavior you are seeing is as implemented though, as you can see from the .NET sources:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directoryinfo.cs,90

The Init method (called from the constructor) does a check for this case, and if it finds it, uses the current working directory (".") instead.  Depending on how you launched the EXE, the current working directory could be the location of the EXE.

Comment: OK, voting your answer up. But any idea WHY "<DriveLetter>:" should be a special case changed to point to "<CurrentDirectory>" instead? Seems that "C:\" should be treated the same as "C:"

Comment: I imagine (and it has come up in other questions) it is to mimic the behavior of CD from the Command Prompt.

> cd c:

doesn't change to the root of the C: drive.  It tells you where on the C drive the current working directory is.  To move to the root, you must CD C:\